# Using Laplace’s method to find the leading-order of an integral with two variables in the exponent

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

> **Past Paper Question:**

Use Laplace’s method to find the leading-order asymptotic behaviour of the integral

$$\begin{align*} & I\left( x\right) =\int _{0}^{\infty }\dfrac {1} {\left( 1+t\right) }e^{x\left( 1-t^{2}\right) }dt\\ & x\rightarrow \infty \end{align*}$$

Wasn't given many example in lecture notes on how to actually apply the Laplace method; we studied the general case mainly. Trying to learn from examples.

> **My Attempt:**
>
> This is an integral of the form $$I\left( x\right) =\int _{a}^{b}f\left( t\right) e^{xg\left( t\right) }dt$$
>   In this case  $f\left(t\right) = \dfrac {1} {1+t}$ and $g\left( t\right) =\left( 1-t^{2}\right)$. Thus the maximum is at $t=0$, so for our purposes this is the "Case $3$ Laplace method: The maximum is at $t=c$ where $a<c<b$ with $f\left( c\right) \neq 0.$"
>
> Step $1$: Split the integral into a local and non-local part and estimate the non-local contribution.
>
> Step $2$: Use Taylor expansion around $c$ to obtain $I\left( x;\varepsilon \right)$, then rescale the integration variable to remove $x$ from the exponential.
>
> Step $3$: Replace both limits of the integration of $I\left( x;\varepsilon \right)$ by $\pm\infty$ and calculate the associated error.
>
> At the moment this fails the definition of case $3$ we apply the following amendment to the question, "Step $0$:"
>   $$I\left( x\right) =\dfrac{1}{2}\int _{-\infty}^{\infty }\dfrac {1} {\left( 1+t\right) }e^{x\left( 1-t^{2}\right) }dt\\$$

Comment: It'd be best to start by rewriting $e^{x(1-t^2)} = e^x e^{-xt^2}$, then pull the $e^x$ out of the integral. After, note that the main contribution to the integral comes from a neighborhood of $t=0$ (why?). Approximate the subexponential factor $1/(1+t)$ near this point to get the leading order behavior (justify why this is true).

Comment: Why is the main contribution $t=0$, how do you approximate "subexponential" terms, and how to justify?

Comment: A detailed application of the Laplace method would be very involved and take a lot of work. It would help me write a better answer for you if you could clarify what you already know. For example, if you're familiar with [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma), then you can use the same idea to justify expanding $1/(1+t) = 1 - t + t^2 - \cdots$ and integrating term by term to get the full asymptotic series. (...)

Comment: (...) Or if you know some pre-packaged version of the Laplace method, such as [the formula under "Other formulations" on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method#Other_formulations), that could be applied to skip a lot of the justification steps.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I've edited the question above quoting from the lecture notes, that's all I have to go on, I hope that helps.

Comment: It is not true that "the maximum is at $t=c$ where $a < c < b$". For this problem, $t=a$. What problems do you have following the suggestions of the notes?

Comment: @AntonioVargas That's a good point... there's also "Case $1$ Laplace method: The maximum is at $t=a$ with $g'\left( a\right) < 0.$" but that also fails the above.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I have found an aside section which works in the notes, I shall adjust the above. It's still in general case though so not very usefull.

Comment: I really suggest reading through the proof of Watson's lemma on the wikipedia page. It can be applied with some small modifications directly to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll consider the integral

$$
J(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t} e^{-xt^2}\,dt,
$$

which is in the form

$$
\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{xg(t)}\,dt
$$

with

$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{1+t} \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(t) = -t^2.
$$

The basic idea of the Laplace method is that the main contribution to the integral $J(x)$ comes from the points $t$ where the integrand $f(t)e^{xg(t)}$ is largest.

As $x$ grows larger, the behavior of the factor $f(t)$ matters less and less; where $g(t)$ is large $f(t)e^{xg(t)}$ will be large, and where $g(t)$ is small $f(t)e^{xg(t)}$ will be small. This means that we're really interested in the maxima of $g(t)$ -- these will be the points $t$ where the integrand $f(t)e^{xg(t)}$ is largest when $x$ is large.

For this problem the function $g(t) = -t^2$ has a single maximum at $t=0$. By the heuristics aboove, the large-$x$ behavior of $J(x)$ should be very similar to the large-$x$ behavior of an integral over a small neighborhood of this point:

$$
J(x) \approx \int_0^\delta \frac{1}{1+t} e^{-xt^2}\,dt.
$$

Our goal is to justify this and to further simplify the integrand to get a simplified expression for the approximation.

---

The first thing we want to do is show that the integral over the region $[\delta,\infty)$ is very small. Here we can get the estimate

$$
\begin{align}
0 \leq \int_\delta^\infty \frac{1}{1+t} e^{-xt^2}\,dt &< \frac{1}{1+\delta} \int_\delta^\infty e^{-xt^2}\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{1+\delta} e^{-\delta^2x} \int_\delta^\infty e^{x (\delta^2-t^2)}\,dt \\
&\leq \frac{1}{1+\delta} e^{-\delta^2x} \int_\delta^\infty e^{\delta^2-t^2}\,dt  \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

for all $x \geq 1$. Thus

$$
J(x) = \int_0^\delta \frac{1}{1+t}e^{-xt^2}\,dt + O\!\left(e^{-\delta^2x}\right) \tag{2}
$$

for all $x \geq 1$.

Our next goal is to study this remaining integral and to show that, to leading order, it is larger than the error term $O(e^{-\delta^2x})$. To do this we will use the fact that

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{1+t} = 1.
$$

Let

$$
h(t) = \frac{1}{1+t} - 1 = \frac{-t}{1+t},
$$

so that

$$
\int_0^\delta \frac{1}{1+t} e^{-xt^2}\,dt = \int_0^\delta e^{-xt^2}\,dt + \int_0^\delta h(t) e^{-xt^2}\,dt. \tag{3}
$$

We expect the second integral to be smaller than the first since $h(t) \approx 0$ for small $\delta$. Indeed,

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\delta e^{-xt^2}\,dt &= \int_0^\infty e^{-xt^2}\,dt - \int_\delta^\infty e^{-xt^2}\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} + O\!\left(e^{-\delta^2 x}\right), \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

where we used an argument very similar to $(1)$ to obtain the $O(\cdots)$ estimate, and

$$
\begin{align}
\left| \int_0^\delta h(t) e^{-xt^2}\,dt \right| &\leq \int_0^\delta |h(t)| e^{-xt^2}\,dt \\
&< \int_0^\delta te^{-xt^2}\,dt \\
&< \int_0^\infty te^{-xt^2}\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2x}. \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

Combining $(4)$ and $(5)$, $(3)$ becomes

$$
\int_0^\delta \frac{1}{1+t} e^{-xt^2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} + O\!\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),
$$

and combining this with $(2)$ yields

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t} e^{-xt^2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} + O\!\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$

for all $x > 1$.