# Laplace's method to obtain the asymptotic approximation

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I have trouble to use Laplace method to find the asymptotic approximation as $x\rightarrow \infty$ of the following integral ($g(t)$ continuous and $g(0)\neq 0$):

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-xt^3}g(t)dt$$

If this is $xt^2$, then I could use  Gaussian integral, which is related to the following nice discussion: 
[Using Laplace’s method to find the leading-order of an integral with two variables in the exponent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222924/using-laplace-s-method-to-find-the-leading-order-of-an-integral-with-two-variabl)

But now it is $xt^3$, how do I solve this problem? please advice, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should go through just as in the linked answer, it's just that
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt^3}dt=x^{-1/3}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^3}dt=\frac13x^{-1/3}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{-2/3}dt=\frac13x^{-1/3}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)$$
So you hope to arrive at the answer
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt^3}g(t)dt\approx\frac13x^{-1/3}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)g(0)$$
I.e. just the same as the previous problem with all the $2$'s changed to $3$'s.

Comment: Could you please explain the first equality?  thanks

Comment: If we let $t=\frac u{x^{1/3}}$ then $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt^3}dt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x\left(\frac u{x^{1/3}}\right)^3}\frac{du}{x^{1/3}}=\frac1{x^{1/3}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u^3}du$$